# Controller not getting a response from factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to clean up my controller by doing http requests in services, but for some reason a functions in my controller is not getting a response from a service.

I have this function in my controller,

```
  $scope.addMovie = function() {

    addMovie.add().then(function(response){
      if(response){
        console.log ('Response')
      } else {
        console.log ('No reposone')
      }
    });
```

And this is the service,

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('addMovie',

    function($http, $q){
      return{
        add: function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
          // Search for release dates using the ID.
          var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
          var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
          var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
          var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
          var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
          var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

          $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              if (status == 200) {

                deferred.resolve(data.results);
                console.log ('Succes getting data')

              } else {
                console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              }

            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              deferred.resolve(false);
            });

            $(".search_results").fadeOut(250);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    })

})();
```

When I run the `$scope.addMovie` function from the controller the console log shows a `Succes getting data` from the service and then a `No response` from the function in the controller. What's missing here?

//edit. I'm now trying to insert the data from the service into a scope in my controller,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  $scope.movieListID = {};
  console.log ('empty' + $scope.movieListID)

  movieAdd.add()
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.movieListID = response;
      console.log ('Not empty' + $scope.movieListID)
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.log ('No search reposone')
    });
}
```

but the console log displays a "undefined" message afther the "Response OK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

addMovie.add().then(function(response){
  if(response){
    console.log ('Response')
  } else {
    console.log ('No reposone')
  }
});
```

to this:

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

addMovie.add()
    .then(function(response){
        console.log ('Response OK');
    })
    .catch(function(responce){
        console.log ('Response error');
    });
```

like this you are actually catching any errors which may be happening in you factory/service...

Comment: Thank you, that showed that the response was succesfull. I'm trying to insert the data from the JSON request into a scope in the controller. `$scope.movieListID = response;
            console.log ($scope.movieListID)` but this returns a "undefined" in the console.

Comment: `$scope.movieListID` is undefined ? at what point ? after your factory runs and return data successfully?

Comment: Sorry I did not post my new `addMovie` function. I've added it to me post. I try to insert the data from the response in a `$scope.movieListID` and when I console.log that scope I get a undefined.

Comment: initialise your `$scope.movieListID = {};` before calling `$scope.addMovie()` function, your response is an object and you are trying to put it into `$scope.movieListId` which doesn't exist at this point yet

Comment: I've initialized the `$scope.movieListID` before doing the function and if I console.log that it returns empty objects. But the `$scope.movieListID` inside the function is undefined. (I've editted my post again).

Comment: In the end the last problem was with `data.results`. Since I was only getting one result chaging that to just `data` fixed the problems!